# Errorcan't bind *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular9

I'm a beginner in Angular and I'm trying to create an application that looks like CapitalistAdventure. But I have an error that I can't resolve and would like to receive some help please. First of all here is how looks my app: 
[image]

The error is located at the app.component.html and it says:

Can't bind to 'product' since it isn't a known property of 'app-product'.
1. If 'app-product' is an Angular component and it has 'product' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-product' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Here is the code that I have for my app.component.html:

```
  <h1><span id="WorldName">{{world.name}}WORLDNAME</span></h1>
  <!--<span id="WorldImage"><img [attr.src]="server+world.logo"/></span>-->
  <div class="UserData">
    <div class="Money">
      <span id="MoneyName">Money:</span>
      <br>
      <!--<span [innerHTML]="world.money | bigvalue"></span>-->
      <span>$</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Buy">
      <span id="BuyName">Buy</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ID">
      <span id="MoneyName">ID :</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Game">
    <div class="UpgradeContainer">
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Unlock')">Unlocks</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Cash')">Cash</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Angels')">Angels</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Managers')">Managers</div>
      <div class="Upgrade" (click)="setModal('Investors')">Investors</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ProductContainer">
      <app-product *ngFor="let product of products" [product]="product"></app-product>
    </div>
</div>
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RestserviceService } from 'src/app/restservice.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
import { BigvaluePipe } from './bigvalue.pipe';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    BigvaluePipe,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
  ],
  providers: [RestserviceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app.component.ts:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RestserviceService } from './restservice.service'; 
import { World, Product, Pallier } from './world';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularProject';
  world: World = new World(); 
  server: String;
  products = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  modal: String;

  constructor(private service: RestserviceService) { 
    this.server = service.getServer(); 
    service.getWorld().then(world => { this.world = world; });   
  }

  setModal(value: String){
    this.modal = value;
  }
}
```

My product.component.html:

```
<div class="Product">
  <div class="ProductInfo">
    <img onclick="alert('Production lancé'), starFabrication() " class="ProductImage" src="./assets/Avatar.jpg">
    <!--<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" class="ProgressBar" [value]="progressbarvalue"></mat-progress-bar>-->
    <div class="ProductNumber">ProductNumber</div>
    <div class="ProductPrice">ProductPrice</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally my product.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/world';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  product: Product;
  @Input()
  set prod(value: Product){
    this.product = value;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

I'm precising but I'm on Angular 9.

Thanks in advance to anybody who would take the time to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `@Input()` decorator to bind to the `product` variable. Try the following

```js
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  product: Product;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

**OR**

If you wish to use the `@Input()` decorator with the setter, then you need to bind to it's name in the template.

Controller

```js
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  product: Product;

  @Input()
  set prod(value: Product){
    this.product = value;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

Template

```html
<app-product *ngFor="let product of products" [prod]="product"></app-product>
```